# Image Classification OpenCV Android

Tags: android, image, opencv, classification

I'm working on a novelty detection project (in Android) using background subtraction. I would like to do simple classification after an object is detected (e.g. Person, Dog, Car, Motorbike). I have read some literature on how to do this using e.g. Bag Of Words, Cascade classifier, but I'm still not sure how to approach the task. Essentially, I want to store the novelty as an image and then label it into some sort of class - like Person, Dog, etc..or even match against a specific person, for example. The number of classes doesn't have to be too large - 2 or 3 even. So my questions are:

1) What's the best/simplest approach to do this? Cascade/Bag of Words/other methods?

2) How can I transport this classifier to my Android app, so that after I store the novelty as an image, I can just pass it to the classifier, which then applies a label. I know Cascade classifiers have associated xml files, but is this the only way?

Sorry if the questions seem trivial, but I've had a difficult time finding literature online.